# How to find a string given sha256 hash value

Tags: python, hash, sha256

I'm solving a puzzle where I have been given a string Y1. Now I have to find a string Y2 such that sha256(concat(Y1,Y2)) < X.

Code snippet :

```
enter code here
import hashlib

from hashlib import sha256
str1 = 'piyushmishra@xyz.com'
#have to find string2, for now lets assign it to be just 'a'
str2 = 'a'
str3 = str1 + str2

hashobj = hashlib.sha256(str3.encode('utf-8'))
val = int.from_bytes(hashobj.digest(), 'big')
print("val = ",val)

X = 46858414364948817464135713501782399740112608689895639803701817211305800534512

if val <= X:
    print("found string ", str2)
else:
    #what to do ?
    pass
```

Comment: Keep generating random strings `Y2` and calculating `sha256(concat(Y1,Y2))` till you find one matching your condition. **If** there was a deterministic way of finding `Y2` satisfying your condition, then `sha256` can be considered as broken.

Comment: Right, I was thinking along the same lines. Just one more clarification. The number of digits in the interger representation of hash values are not fixed right? different strings might have different lengths ?

Comment: Right, different strings can have sha256 int representation of different lengths. The max cap would be `2^256`

Comment: cool thanks. This was helpful